# Ansible: combine dicts that have relation (foreign key / primary key)

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I fetch data from netbox in Ansible in order to make data accessible.

There are devices like that:

```yaml
{
     "key": 22,
     "value": {
         "name": "mysmartswitch.libcom.de",
     ...
}
```

Then there are interfaces that point to the foreign key of a device. There may be multiple interfaces that point to a device. Example object.

```yaml
{
    "key": 48,
    "value": {
        "name": "eth2",
        "device": {
            "display": "mysmartswitch.libcom.de",
            "id": 22,
            "name": "mysmartswitch.libcom.de",
            "url": "https://netbox.libcom.de/api/dcim/devices/17/"
        },
    ...
}
```

Last there are IP address object that relate to an interface. There may be multiple IP addresses that point to an interface.

```yaml
{
    "key": 372,
    "value": {
        "assigned_object_id": 48,
        "assigned_object_type": "dcim.interface",
        "address": "fd01:1:3:4::10/64",
        "family": {
            "label": "IPv6",
            "value": 6
        },
```

So what I wand to have in the end is a structure like that:

```yaml
mydevices:
  mysmartswitch:
    interfaces:
      eth2:
        ip4: 1.2.3.4/29
        ip6: fd01:1:2:3::10/64
```

You get the idea. My [current approach](https://github.com/imp1sh/ansible_managemynetwork/blob/main/roles/ansible_netbox2yaml/tasks/devices.yml) is to iterate through every possible combination:

1. Iterate through devices
2. Iterate through interfaces
3. If interface fits to device
4. Iterate over ips
5. If IP fits to interface, add or combine to dictionary item.
   See my Ansible collection to understand details.

The problem with my approach is that it kind of takes forever. Those nested loops currently take about 15 minutes to finish on a really fast System, while not having very much items.

What is best practice in those kind of situations? I thought about using `community.general.json_query()` but I can't wrap my head around that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lists for testing

```yaml
    devices:
      - key: 22
        value:
          name: mysmartswitch.libcom.de

    interfaces:
      - key: 48
        value:
          name: eth2
          device:
              display: mysmartswitch.libcom.de
              id: 22
              name: mysmartswitch.libcom.de
              url: https://netbox.libcom.de/api/dcim/devices/17/

    ips:
      - key: 372
        value:
          assigned_object_id: 48
          assigned_object_type: dcim.interface
          address: fd01:1:3:4::10/64
          family:
            label: IPv6
            value: 6
```

---

Create dictionaries

```yaml
    ifc_dict: "{{ dict(interfaces|json_query(ifc_query)|groupby('id')) }}"
    ifc_query: '[].{id: value.device.id,
                    ifc: value.name,
                    ips: key}'

    ips_dict: "{{ dict(ips|json_query(ips_query)|groupby('id')) }}"
    ips_query: '[].{id: value.assigned_object_id,
                    address: value.address,
                    family: value.family.value}'
```

gives

```yaml
  ifc_dict:
    22:
    - id: 22
      ifc: eth2
      ips: 48

  ips_dict:
    48:
    - address: fd01:1:3:4::10/64
      family: 6
      id: 48
```

Iterate *devices* and create the dictionary

```yaml
    mydevices_str: |
      {% for device in devices %}
      {{ device.value.name }}:
        interfaces:
      {% for i in ifc_dict[device.key] %}
          {{ i.ifc }}:
            ipv4: {{ ips_dict[i.ips]|selectattr('family', 'eq', 4)|map(attribute='address')|list }}
            ipv6: {{ ips_dict[i.ips]|selectattr('family', 'eq', 6)|map(attribute='address')|list }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    mydevices: "{{ mydevices_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  mydevices:
    mysmartswitch.libcom.de:
      interfaces:
        eth2:
          ipv4: []
          ipv6:
          - fd01:1:3:4::10/64
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    devices:
      - key: 22
        value:
          name: mysmartswitch.libcom.de

    interfaces:
      - key: 48
        value:
          name: eth2
          device:
              display: mysmartswitch.libcom.de
              id: 22
              name: mysmartswitch.libcom.de
              url: https://netbox.libcom.de/api/dcim/devices/17/

    ips:
      - key: 372
        value:
          assigned_object_id: 48
          assigned_object_type: dcim.interface
          address: fd01:1:3:4::10/64
          family:
            label: IPv6
            value: 6

    ifc_dict: "{{ dict(interfaces|json_query(ifc_query)|groupby('id')) }}"
    ifc_query: '[].{id: value.device.id,
                    ifc: value.name,
                    ips: key}'
                    

    ips_dict: "{{ dict(ips|json_query(ips_query)|groupby('id')) }}"
    ips_query: '[].{id: value.assigned_object_id,
                    address: value.address,
                    family: value.family.value}'

    mydevices_str: |
      {% for device in devices %}
      {{ device.value.name }}:
        interfaces:
      {% for i in ifc_dict[device.key] %}
          {{ i.ifc }}:
            ipv4: {{ ips_dict[i.ips]|selectattr('family', 'eq', 4)|map(attribute='address')|list }}
            ipv6: {{ ips_dict[i.ips]|selectattr('family', 'eq', 6)|map(attribute='address')|list }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    mydevices: "{{ mydevices_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ifc_dict
    - debug:
        var: ips_dict
    - debug:
        var: mydevices
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The original data actually doesn't come in lists, but in a dict. I will try to send it through dict2items.

Comment: There are plenty of IP address objects that do not have an association to an interface at all. I can't see how to filter them out. with the api_filters in nb_lookup. Can I somehow filter them out within the json_query statement? The IP records in question have the assigned_object_id set to null.

Comment: 1) Your original data come actually in lists. See your [code](https://github.com/imp1sh/ansible_managemynetwork/blob/main/roles/ansible_netbox2yaml/tasks/devices.yml). The results of *query* are lists *nb_devices_fetched, nb_interfaces_fetched, nb_ips_fetched*. Then you iterate *loop: "{{ nb_devices_fetched }}*. 2) Open new question and make it [mre]. You're welcome.

Comment: I was able to use your help in order to optimize my task by a huge factor. My nested loops took about 16 minutes, now it's done in about 10 seconds. If anyone is interested, here is the result.
https://github.com/imp1sh/ansible_managemynetwork/blob/main/roles/ansible_netbox2yaml/tasks/devices.yml
https://github.com/imp1sh/ansible_managemynetwork/blob/main/roles/ansible_netbox2yaml/templates/netbox_devices.jinja2